# use of addEventListener() in js

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have seen some of the documentation on `addEventListener()`, but I didn't understand the purpose of the second and third arguments of the same function. Please explain it with reference to the following code:

```
// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

The secong argument is the function you want to run when the event triggers. You can either use an anonymous function or pass a name of an already defined one..

The third is for Mozilla only..: ([from docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener))

> **useCapture** (Optional)
>
> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes
>   to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the
>   specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before
>   being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events
>   which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener
>   designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed
>   explanation. If not specified, useCapture defaults to false.

Which basically means the the event will not be triggered when bubbling from a child element.

Comment: The question is not a good fit for SO, so please don't encourage by answering. The OP could have found his answer by googling, as proven by pablochan's comment.

Comment: For some questions even a noob like me can say "This is a pretty simple one !" that doesnt mean it is not a good fit for SO.I respect your reputation though.

Answer (score 0):

**Events**

the old way to listen events was to append the "on" named event on the element.

some events:window.onload,element.onclick,document.onkeyup....

the param you give is the function you want to execute.

```
window.onload=func
```

but in this case u can pass only one function (so if in your document you have ultiple window.onload the last one will always overwrite the previous one)

So they created addEventListener (or in older ie AttachEvent)

1. every Eventlistener you create adds a new one and so does not overwrite the previous ones.
2. by passing a named function u can remove them with removeEventListener.
3. the events are mostly the same but you don't add 'on' in the front of the event.

---

```
window.addEventListener('load',func,false);
```

the first param in addEventListener is the event you wanna listen.

the second param is the function you wanna execute

and the third is well described in the @Yotam Omer post

AS the event happens your second paramete (the function) will be executed and send the information about the event to that function.

so if you want to get moredetails of every event you need to define the first param of your function.

in this case 'event'

```
var func=function(event){console.log(event)}
```

this function logs every information you need about the event.

---

**Now to describe specifically your code**

this is an object containing the keys pressed (and hold down) on your keyboard.

```
var keysDown = {};
```

the first event handler listens to a key press event.
so if you "keydown" the inline created function recieves the event information 'e'.
As the event is a keyboard event you also get the 'keyCode' and that is the numerical rappresentation of the key you pressed.
the function itself does only add the pressed key keyCode to the previous created object
'keysDown'.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
```

the second handler listens to the 'keyup' event.
passing the event 'e' information with the keyCode .
and if the keyCode is present in the Object 'keysDown' it will be deleted.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
   delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);
```

so while pressing your keyboard the 'keysDown' object knows always exactly which keys are hold down.this could be usefull for operations like multiple keypress (shift+ctrl+letter) or just to keep track which keys are hold down.

you can easely test the result by logging the object.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
    console.log(keysDown)
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks cooco! nicely explained! wish I could vote up your answer soon.I am new to SO.